# How to give an Azure SQL DB instance a private IP?

Tags: azure, azure-networking, azure-sql

I have an Azure SQL DB. Is it possible to give it a local IP address for connections from within my network and vnet so that it forces the traffic over expressroute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of September 2019, Microsoft now has 'private endpoints' in preview for Azure SQL DB.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-private-endpoint-overview

Answer (score 2):

You cannot give Azure SQL Db any specific IP address. However, you can configure service endpoint of Azure SQL Db to allow any resources inside VNET or from a specific IP. It means inbound to Azure SQL Db can be controlled. It would be a hope to have User-Defined Routing to support Azure SQL Db to route traffic to ExpressRoute.

Comment: VNet Service Endpoints for Azure SQL Database now generally available https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/vnet-service-endpoints-for-azure-sql-database-now-generally-available/

Comment: @KevinBurandt it is inbound control only. It means with the service endpoint, you can allow inbound network traffic from subnet's service endpoint enabled to connect to Azure SQL Database.